# ember AfterModel of one to many creates empty array

Tags: arrays, ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models. Session and Test.

```
App.Session = DS.Model.extend({
    tests: DS.hasMany('test', {async: true}/*, {inverse: 'sessionID'}*/),
});

App.Test = DS.Model.extend({
    session: DS.belongsTo('session', {async: true}, {inverse:'tests'}),
});
```

And I have a route to fetch the tests array (it isn't included in the JSON coming from the server)

```
App.SessionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.get('store').find('session', params.session_id);
    },

    afterModel: function(model) {
        var promise;
        promise = this.get('store').find('test', {
            sessionId: model.get('id')
        });
        return this.controllerFor('tests').set('model', promise);
    }
});
```

The thing is that the tests array in Session is still empty after the fetch.
`{{ tests.length }}`
is 0

When I log to console what is returned in AfterModel - I do have the data - however it is nested in a triple nested object (don't know if it is how it should be or not)

Class {content: Class, **ember1416498812066: "ember400", __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta**: Object, constructor: function…}**ember1416498812066: "ember400"__ember_meta**: Object__nextSuper: undefinedcontent: Class__ember1416498812066: "ember525"**ember_meta**: Object__nextSuper: undefinedcontent: Class__ember1416498812066: "ember524"**ember_meta**: Object__nextSuper: undefinedcontent: **Array[1]** isLoaded: truemanager: Classmeta: Objectquery: Objectstore: Classtype: BackslashUi.Test__proto__: ClassisFulfilled: true__proto__: Class__proto__: Class

The test object exists nicely in the ember chrome plugin (in "data" section)

Does anyone know what is wrong/how I can even debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the model for the tests controller to the promise; set it to the **result** of the promise when it fulfills, and return the promise so that Ember will know when to go ahead.

```
afterModel: function(model) {
    var testsController = this.controllerFor('tests');
    var promise = this.get('store').find('test', {
        sessionId: model.get('id')
    });
    return promise.then(function(tests) {
        testsController.set('model', tests);
    });
}
```

The automatic handling of promises for models is something that happens specifically in the context of the route's `model` hook. `model` examines the return value, sees if it is a promise. If it is, it waits for it to resolve before proceeding to pass the result of the promise to `setupController` etc. You can't just randomly set models to promises and expect them to work. Nobody is watching them or waiting for them to resolve or `then`'ing off them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting 0 in <p>{{ tests.length }}</p> (assuming I'm right in the handlebars) - Must I override setupController?

Comment: prined tests inside the than - it is an array of 1 element - but in session data (looking with ember inspector plugin) - it's undefined (and as said {{tests.length}} is 0